# How to enable RemoteIPProxyProtocol conditionally in apache only if connection contains proxy header?

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, configuration, load-balancing, apache2

We have multiple ec2 servers for our application which are served through aws load balancer. Now because of our specific requirement, we had to use tcp load balancers.

With tcp load balancers, we were not able to track user's IP, however after I applied certain settings, the load balancer adds user's IP as a proxy header and then forwards the packet to EC2.

At EC2 (where we are using Apache), to handle the packets with proxy headers, we needed to enable RemoteIPProxyProtocol. And it works for the traffic through these load-balancers. However we have a number of hosts/domains, which are directly configured to some of the EC2s i.e the traffic for these hosts do not route through load balancer and connection packet does not contain proxy header, and therefor for these, the apache stops working as it needs all HTTP connections with proxy header.

What I need is, that can we conditionally enable RemoteIPProxyProtocol, by detecting that if connection has a proxy header or not ? Also please note I cannot use host-names for conditions, as I have hundreds of them and they will keep increasing ??

Kindly Help.

NOTE: I have tried to forward the traffic from load-balancer to EC2 on 81 and 444 port and for those ports in apache I enabled RemoteIPProxyProtocol, however I needed to forward the traffic from 444 to 443 for SSL decryption, but that didn't work.

Originally Posted On:. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587257/how-to-enable-remoteipproxyprotocol-conditionally-in-apache-only-if-connection-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researching, I found that there is no way to enable RemoteIPProxyProtocol by detecting proxy header.

However, I have achieved it by using HAProxy on the same server as the apache.
I forwarded the traffic from load balancer to EC2 on ports 580 & 5443 rather that 80 and 443. While I set up the HAProxy to listen to 580 & 5443 port on the same ec2. The HAProxy will then parse the proxy protocol header from packet, remove it and forward the actual client ip (found in proxy protocol header) to apache on ports 80 & 443.

It works !!